# port forwarding doesn't work

Tags: router, ip, port-forwarding, port

I'm trying to open a port to play a game with my friend and it's not working: 
 when scanning ports on my public IP via a port scanner, it shows no results for any ports.

**Router port forward settings:**

- [image: Screenshot 1]

**Port scan results:**

- [image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Is the game actually running (and waiting for connections) when you do the scan? Does the public IP address shown by the scanner match the one shown by your router's status page?

Comment: @user1686 yes, the game server is running while I'm doing the scan and I can't find my public IP address on the router (I search on google for it.)

Comment: @GrigorijeSkipina If a router's firewall is configured correctly, you shouldn't see any open ports when using a WAN side port-scanner, as that traffic should be auto blocked by the router's stateful firewall.

Comment: @JW0914 I turned completely off the router firewall but there are the same problem and my friend can't connect to the game server

Comment: @GrigorijeSkipina **A WAN-facing router's firewall should _never_ be disabled**, as it's the sole protection downstream devices have from WAN-side traffic... client devices connected to a router are never intended to be directly exposed to the internet.  Disabling the firewall also disables NAT, so DNAT would no longer function.

Comment: @JW0914 ok thanks, I restored the firewall, but what about my problem? Do I need to call my ISP or there's another way to fix it?

Comment: @GrigorijeSkipina ISPs don't have the capabilities to block DNAT, as a modem doesn't speak that language and has no clue how to route packets, it just sends and receives them.  DNAT is fairly simple to troubleshoot, as it's either the router or the client.  I'm not familiar with the router, or it's WebUI, that you're using, so I would check the help section/manual for that router to ensure everything is correctly set up for DNAT on that router, and if so, check the client's firewall.

Comment: @JW0914 so, I checked everything I could (DNAT, DMZ, UnPnP, IGMP, RIP, Router Firewall, and my PC firewall...) I also downloaded PFPortChecker, but it says "We were not able to ping your router" :/

Comment: @GrigorijeSkipina It's never recommended to use UPnP because it's not secure, however simply to troubleshoot, disable the DNAT rule you created and enable UPnP on the router, then attempt the connection.  If the connection fails, it's not the router; disable UPnP & manually stop it's service if available, then re-enable the DNAT rule.  Superuser isn't really conducive to troubleshooting, so I would recommend using either a forum for the game you're playing or a forum for the OS that's installed on the local machine for troubleshooting.

Comment: @GrigorijeSkipina Here in INDIA, generally ip is behind NAT. The IP you might be seeing in google might be IP of a group of people to cut the cost. you can check by pinging the public IP.  Ask you ISP about it. Else it is possible that game server is listening on some other port.

Comment: Thank you for the response guys, I fixed my problem by calling my ISP and they gave me a public IP.